# vanilla javascript animation only working for one element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote an animation to fade a list item off of the page, but it is only working for the first class that has the class name .grid-item, why is this happening and how can I fix this problem? It works perfectly fine for the first grid item and then nothing for the others.

```js
let addCart = document.querySelector(".add-btn");

let item = document.querySelector(".grid-item");

addCart.addEventListener("click", function() {
  item.style.animation = "add-cart";
  item.style.animationDuration = "3s";

  setTimeout(() => {
    item.style.animation = "none";
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
@keyframes add-cart {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    z-index: 1000;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(210%) scale(0.3);
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  51% {
    transform: translateY(-110%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

.animation {
  animation: add-cart;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-item">
  <h3 class="title">Cano One</h3>
  <div class="img-container">
    <img class="bike-image" src="img/bike1.png" alt="bike" />
  </div>
  <p class="item-price">$2850</p>
  <button class="add-btn"><p class="plus">+</p></button>
</div>
<div class="grid-item">
  <h3 class="title">Predator</h3>
  <div class="img-container">
    <img class="bike-image" src="img/bike2.png" alt="bike" />
  </div>
  <p class="item-price">$2010</p>
  <button class="add-btn"><p class="plus">+</p></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `querySelectorAll` and then use `forEach` to loop over all elements to add listeners.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `querySelectorAll` so the `click` event listener can be added to all the elemlents.

```js
let gridItems = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item");
gridItems.forEach(item => {
  const button = item.querySelector('.add-btn')
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    item.style.animation = "add-cart";
    item.style.animationDuration = "3s";

    setTimeout(() => {
      item.style.animation = "none";
    }, 1000);
  })
})
```